# How to convert two rating columns into one rating type and one rating

Tags: excel, transpose

In Excel, how can I convert two rating columns "CCA" and "MMA"  with the rating value into one rating type column and the rating value column. I tried Copy and Paste with Transpose but it is not working as I want.

Please see the screenshot below to be clear.

[image]

I'm fine with the duplicate records of the total rows.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

OK here's another solution working with formulas. Once you have finished all following steps, next time everything will be automatically changed.

Start with the same 3*4 status in Sheet 1.

Now turn to Sheet 2. It should be a totally blank sheet.

**Title**

A1: Proj

B1: Rating Type

C1: Rating

**Porject**

A2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MOD(ROW()+1,3)+2)` (change 3 to 1310)

Then drag and expend downward until row 2*1310+1.

Finally each unit in this column will be filled with same formulas above.

**Rating Type**

B2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$1:$C$1,1,IF(ROW()-1>3,2,1))` (change 3 to 1310)

Then drag and expend downward until row 2*1310+1.
Finally each unit in this column will be filled with same formulas above.

**Rating**

C2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$C$4,MOD(ROW()+1,3)+1,IF(ROW()-1>3,2,1))` (change 3 to 1310)

Then drag and expend downward until row 2*1310+1.

Finally each unit in this column will be filled with same formulas above.

NOW there should be the same result as yours.

---

OLD ANSWER

I will try to show you how to finish this transformation manually. It's not too complex.

[image]

Set up title of new columns:

[image]

Copy and paste all project names twice:

[image]

Input CCA and MMA for the two groups of projects. Dragging right-bottom point of the unit would be easy to expend texts:

[image]

Copy and paste CCA column:

[image]

Copy and paste MMA column:

[image]

Comment: Oh, there is 1310 records and it will change every week. So i still need some kinds of auto process.